# What is "fresco activities"?

Tags: word-meaning

An excerpt
Outdoor adventure:

> From the stately flanks of its Cascade volcanoes to the stony shores of its myriad waterways, the region offers an unmatched wealth of all **fresco activities**.

What is "fresco activities"?

Answer (score 16):

I think the correct expression is ***[al fresco](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/al-fresco):***

> (especially of food and eating) outside:
>
> - an al fresco lunch on the patio
> - Most summer evenings we eat al fresco.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

> the region offers an unmatched wealth of *al fresco activities.* (outdoors activities)

Comment: When I looked up an excerpt of this phrase on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22myriad+waterways%2C+the+region+offers+an+unmatched+wealth+of%22&oq=%22myriad+waterways%2C+the+region+offers+an+unmatched+wealth+of%22), I found some quotes with _al fresco_ but some with _all fresco_. It appears to be a typo in several Russian sites (perhaps autocorrected in?).

Comment: You can delete "I think". You are correct.